# Hashing an array to an integer

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

I have a mapping from an int[2] array to weights. So [2, 3] -> 5, [4,5] -> 6 etc. Is it a workable strategy to use a HashMap where I do h.put(Arrays.deepHashCode(a), w)? I have a large amount of data and I want to be able to quickly look up weights given coordinates x,y. I am seeing bugs where h.get(hashcode) seems to be returning me unexpected values later. Not always but occasionally. Is this possibly an artifact of the fact that [x,y] and [a, b] might occasionally have the same deepHashCode()? I will try to boil it down to a small piece of code but currently its hard to isolate this problem.

EDIT:
I isolated the problem. Turns out Arrays.deepHashCode([2, 74]) is same as Arrays.deepHashCode([3, 43]) [both return 1097 on my system]. I incorrectly thought that the get() would resolve collisions for me.. but it can't since its mapping a hashcode to a value and the array key is no longer in existence when I did the put().

Comment: Yes, some code will be very helpful. Also, what do you mean by `unexpected values`?  You seem to imply that you sometimes get the same hashCode for 2 different objects.  Is that it?  Because that's not disallowed.

Comment: I store thousands of [x,y] tuples (key) to weight (value) mapping in the hashtable. Later I am reading back [x,y] to get back the weight and its returning unexpected values sometimes (which are not what I entered). You are right that I need to provide a clearer question with code. Will see if I can run a small program to isolate this. I suppose that [x, y] -> w1 can be overwritten by [a,b] -> w2 if [x,y].hashcode and [a,b].hashcode are same but it should be rare.

Comment: I agree with @sstan.  We need to see some code to 1) try to understand the problem and 2) try to figure out why your implementation is not working.

Comment: See edit above - I isolated the problem but now I need to figure out a better way to allow me to do constant time mappings from a tuple to a weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never assume that hash codes are unique.  Always remember that `return 0` is a valid implementation of `hashCode()`.

You should really be writing a pair or a tuple class instead of using arrays or manually putting in hash codes that you should not assume are unique.

Comment: My problem is that I want a fast lookup of weight given tuple, i.e Mapping of (x, y) -> w. How can I do that without hashmaps?

Comment: I didn't say don't use hash maps.  I said to write a pair or tuple type to use as the key in the hash map.

Comment: I think I dont follow very well. If I use my own data type like pair or tuple, I still need to compute a unique hashcode right?

Comment: No, you need to compute a half-decent hash code.  As long as you write a correct equals implementation, however, your map will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the right direction. Using a Pair class helped me optimize the code a bit more as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays as keys in a map is a bad idea, as their `hashCode` implementation is not based on their contents. You should instead use a collection in place of your array(s), or a class that wraps your array and properly implements `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: I am using deepHashCode() which should be based on contents